# how to decrypt with random nonce in AES encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, nonce

I am new in cryptography. I need to encrypt a text using AES with some configuration

```
Encryption mode: GCM
Key size: 256 bits
Nonce size: 96 bits
MAC size: 128 bits
```

As AES is a symmetric algo. so i have a secrete key. I googled and found

> nonce is a random number used to make sure a message is unique

But i have a doubt, how i can perform decryption, if nonce is a random number. do i need to store nonce along with each encryption. or any other way i need to split nonce, cipher and mac using key.
how can i use the provided configuration for encryption.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But i have a doubt, how i can perform decryption, if nonce is a random number. do i need to store nonce along with each encryption.

Yes, result of the encryption stored/sent is nonce, ciphertext, mac.

> how i can perform decryption, if nonce is a random number

Nonce is randomly generated when encrypting the input and the nonce is then passed along the ciphertext (very often the nonce is prepended as the first block). Indeed you need THE SAME nonce value when decrypting, then the nonce is part of the input for decrpytion, not random

> or any other way i need to split nonce, cipher and mac using key. how can i use the provided configuration for encryption.

There is a [standardized message format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2630) for encrypted document or [encrypted XML messages](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss-m/wss/v1.1.1/csprd01/wss-SOAPMessageSecurity-v1.1.1-csprd01.html), but these are pretty  pretty complex.

In reality - for simpler applications very often we see the encryption output composed as `IV || ciphertext || MAC`  (as concatenation). IV and MAC are having fixed length, so you can cut them out and use the parameters for decryption.

> decryption is happening on different machine and language. they have shared only a key for encryption. same key they are using for decryption. if i will add any random value as nonce then how hey will know what logic i have used for nonc

It doesn't matter until you provide the same input. As already mentioned - you may pass the IV (nonce) as part of the message and before decryption separate the nonce and original ciphertext.

BTW: I have [a few encryption examples](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) linked

Comment: can you please give me some better idea how can i share nonce and MAC. i mean do i need to store in Database along with primary key or can be other way.

Comment: You can store the binary nonce and MAC any way you want, as long as you store it with the ciphertext, **not** with the GCM key. If you mean "primary database key that identifies the message / ciphertext", then the answer is probably yes.

Answer (score 5):

Precisely, the nonce must be stored with the cipher text.

Remember, the nonce being part of the cipher text doesn't give the attacker any advantage.

From **Wikipedia**:

> An **initialization** **vector** has different security requirements than a key, so the IV usually does **not need to be secret**. However, in most cases, it is important that an initialization vector is **never reused** under the **same key**. For CBC and CFB, reusing an IV leaks some information about the first block of plaintext, and about any common prefix shared by the two messages.

The purpose of initialization vector is to insert some randomness the encryption process so that an attacker cannot know when two identical plaintext messages have been encrypted with the same key.

IV is required for decryption, you can simply send it concatenated with the ciphertext.

`IV || ciphertext`

The most common way to transmit an initialization vector is, indeed, to prepend it immediately before the ciphertext.

Comment: tats mean for decryption nonce is needed along with secret key?

Comment: @nitinverma yes, you can simply concatenate the IV and Ciphertext

Comment: how a receiver will understand, what is the random generated nonce.

Comment: @nitinverma well it doesn't matter as the IV is effectively treated as the first block, you shouldn't have to parse it out, however even if you wish to, you can simply strip the first x number of bits as needed, Pls mark question as answered.

Comment: i am not able to understand how the decryption will happen without knowing nonce. could you please provide some example for encryption and decryption

Comment: You must encrypt, send cipher text and IV. Decrypt with same key and IV. You can send the IV as part of the ciphertext in the clear. Which part don’t you get? What language are you even using?

Comment: actually issue is, decryption is happening on different machine and language. they have shared only a key for encryption. same key they are using for decryption. if i will add any random value as nonce then how hey will know what logic i have used for nonce. i am using JAVA

Comment: **For GCM** (and any other AE mode) you must also send the **auth tag** (MAC) from the encryptor to the decryptor. It is fairly common to append the tag to the _end_ of the ciphertext, especially in Java where the provider does this for you (and if you want some other format you must peel it off and later tack it back on).

Comment: "The purpose of initialization vector is to insert some randomness the encryption process" I'd say you're inserting "uniqueness" not randomness. If randomness where required then the use of serial nonces would fail for modes such as GCM (and they do not). The required randomness is already present in the key. Modes like CBC do require an *unpredictable* IV, but that's still something different from a random IV.