# how to decrypt files with random nonce

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, nonce

Iam encrypting multiple files using [chacha-poly1305](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/aead/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead.ChaCha20Poly1305) and using KDF for password. I can encrypt files but how do i decrypt with random nonce. The function says [NEVER REUSE NONCE](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/aead/#:%7E:text=NEVER%20REUSE%20A%20NONCE) but then how i do decrypt using random nonces.

If i reuse nonce for file encryption then how safe is it.

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029634/how-to-decrypt-with-random-nonce-in-aes-encryption) has been asked but the solution wasn't good

Eg code

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead import ChaCha20Poly1305

kdfpass = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=5
)

password = kdfpass.derive(b'Password@123')
salt = b'123456789520'
original = b'Hellow123'

chacha = ChaCha20Poly1305(password)

encrypted = chacha.encrypt(os.urandom(12), original, salt)
print(encrypted)

decrypted = chacha.decrypt(os.urandom(12), encrypted, salt)
print(decrypted)
```

Is there a way to save the nonce and retrieve it for decrypting.

Also wanted to know if chacha-poly1305 is a good enough encryption.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Voting to close this as not reproducible. As for the nonce warning, it says that you should not reuse nonce _with the same key_.

Comment: @bereal the error is InvalidTag

Comment: I tried this, and it worked fine, please share a [mcve].

Comment: @bereal updated the code in question

Comment: A reproducible example is something I can copy and paste as is into a new file, run and see the problem.

Comment: Of course, you have to use the same nonce for decryption as you used for encryption.  _NEVER REUSE A NONCE with a key_ refers to different encryptions.

Comment: @Topaco yes but for file encryption and decryption it needs to be same and thats what iam looking for. Also if i used same nonce will it compromise on the encryption of the files.

Comment: @bereal added minimal reproducible example

Comment: Well, I don't understand the problem. In the example you use different nonces for encryption and decryption and wonder why it doesn't work. Solution: Use the same nonce for decryption that you used for the related encryption. To do this, the (not secret) nonce must be passed to the decrypting side along with the ciphertext (typically concatenated).

Comment: "Also if i used same nonce will it compromise on the encryption of the files" - no, it will not. Like I and @Topaco said above, you should not use nonce multiple times for encryption with the same key. But of course it's ok to use the same nonce for decryption. I mean, how could using the same nonce for decryption compromise anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you're using different nonces for encrypting and decrypting.  The purpose of a nonce in this case is to allow the reuse of a key without compromising the security.

It's safe to use the same nonce for encrypting a message and decrypting it, and in fact you must do so for things to work.  However, you must not reuse the same key/nonce pair for multiple messages.  That will both allow tampering with the message and also allow a crib-dragging attack which can leak the plaintext.

ChaCha20-Poly1305 is considered strong and robust.  However, because of the small nonce size, you should not use random nonces with it because of the risk of collisions.  Instead, generate a random salt from a CSPRNG for each message, derive both the key and nonce for that message from the KDF, and then prepend the salt to the message instead of the nonce.  When you decrypt, remove the salt, re-derive the key and nonce, and then use those to decrypt.  Alternately, if you have XChaCha20-Poly1305 (note the *X*), then the nonce size (192 bits) is large enough to use random nonces.

Also, note that PBKDF2, while still secure, is no longer considered state of the art as a password-based key derivation function and scrypt or Argon2id are preferred.  In addition, 5 iterations is absurdly weak and your proposed code is vulnerable to a brute force attack, especially with a password of that strength.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, really appreciate it, the password and iterations are just example to run it fast, gonna increase the iterations to 100k in the actual code and maybe use scrypt instead of KDF